# Boot2Docker (1.3.0) stop starting. Now getting: "Error requesting socket: exit status 255"

Tags: boot2docker

When I run:

```
$ boot2docker start
```

I get:

```
Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start...
.................
Started.
  Trying to get Docker socket one more time
Error requesting socket: exit status 255
Auto detection of the VM's Docker socket failed.
Please run `boot2docker -v up` to diagnose.
```

I have delete the iso and redownloaded it, and reran init.  I have even reinstalled it.  If I run it with the -v flag I get a bunch of these:

```
executing: /usr/bin/ssh ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -p 2022 -i /Users/cholmok/.ssh/id_boot2docker docker@localhost grep tcp:// /proc/$(cat /var/run/docker.pid)/cmdline
Error requesting socket: exit status 255
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error, after I upgraded to 1.2.

For me the problem was already exported `DOCKER_HOST` env variable.

Try to unset it and run `boot2docker up` again.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out what the problem was:  I had a corrupted hosts file.

Comment: Yep, happened to me too.  Make sure you have a line `127.0.0.1 localhost` in your `/etc/hosts` file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your hosts file contains the line:

`127.0.0.1 localhost`

You will need *sudo* to edit the hosts file (`sudo vi /etc/hosts`).

---

*Disclaimer: I had this issue too and found Dave's comment to Chris' answer was the solution in my case*

Answer (score 0):

You need to quit boot2docker

End of the background processes

restart boot2docker up